# Countiong the number of bifurcation and ending points of every contour of the binary image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour

I am trying to implement [this paper's](http://elcvia.cvc.uab.es/article/view/108) algorithm. I've done the contour detection and normalization parts, also feature extraction step1. feature extraction includes 2 steps and in second step you must count the number of bifurcation and endings of every contour. can you give me a clue to start this part? I can't find a solution. the first parts were more clear and although this is my first experience with mat lab I could find the way but step2 seems harder to me.
 any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) especially at the `'branchpoints'` and `'endpoints'` options.

Comment: Thanks Shai for your answer but I don't think this gonna work  in my case. I want to count the number of Es and Bs for each contour ( or I must say connected component ) individually in a way that at the end I have an array with n=number of contours rows and m=2 number of rows which is bifurcations and endings.